# Can a spontaneous caster use higher level slots to cast non-heightened lower level spells?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e, spell-slots

I'm an Oracle. I've picked up Divine Access (Ragathiel) which adds True Strike to my spell list. I've also added it to my spell repertoire as a 1-st level spell.

Since it is not one of my signature spells I can't heighten it (not that it provides any bonus effect by being heightened).

I'm out of 1-st level spell slots. Can I use a 2-nd level spell slot to cast True Strike?

Comment: It's worth noting that spells can always be Heightened (if they're signature or known at multiple levels), even if there isn't a Heightened entry; this is important for spells like [Dispel Magic](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=78).

Comment: I see. I read the "Heightened Spells" and "Heightened Spontaneous Spells" rules again and now I'm fairly sure the answer to my original question is "no".

Comment: Is there a downside to casting a spell "heightened" that you want to avoid when using the higher level slot? Why do you want to cast it with a higher level slot without heightening it, what are the benefits?

Comment: @RevenantBacon There are usually (at least minor) benefits to Heightening, but you cannot freely Heighten spells; for a spontaneous caster you must either take the spell at every level you want to cast (you usually get 4 spells per level) *or* select it as a Signature spell, of which you only have one per spell level. The *ability* to Heighten spells is limited, especially for spontaneous spellcasters.

Comment: There is also the points raised in this [related question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/180010/are-heightened-effects-of-spells-optional) about having to use the "improved" effects of heightened spells even if they're not beneficial in a specific situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Signs point to... no

It's hard to prove a negative... but I can find no rules that allow "downcasting" spell slots.

The full rules on spell slots are [here](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=270). There is (very shaky) evidence against downcasting in the [Heightening Spells](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=273) section

> Both prepared and spontaneous spellcasters **can cast a spell at a higher spell level than that listed for the spell. This is called heightening** the spell. A prepared spellcaster can heighten a spell by preparing it in a higher-level slot than its normal spell level, while a spontaneous spellcaster can heighten a spell by casting it using a higher-level spell slot[...]

More importantly, no mention, anywhere, is ever about using spell slots for spells that are not *that* level, either as written or by using the rules on Heightening. The language from the various spontaneous spellcasters is

> You can cast any spell in your spell repertoire by using a spell slot of an appropriate spell level.

Unfortunately, what constitutes "appropriate" is never defined, and the dictionary definition, "suitable or proper in the circumstances" isn't much help either. However, lacking further clarification, "appropriate" would *seem to mean* that it is the "correct" level, the exact level, spell for that spell slot.

Comment: The rules related to this are debated (multiple times, but this seems to be the most full forum) at the [Paizo Rules forums](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs42x18?Can-I-do-this-Basically-substituting-out). Check there for more information and the opposite take.

Answer (score 5):

If the consensus is that you cannot use a higher spell slot for lower level spells by yourself. There is a rule for specifically this when using a staff with that spell listed.

> When a spontaneous spellcaster Activates a staff, they can expend 1
> charge from the staff and one of their spell slots to cast a spell
> from the staff of the same level (or lower) as the expended spell
> slot.

The **Staff of Divination** has True Strike listed. So one option could be to burn your 1st level spell slots first, then use 2nd level slots + staff charges after that. Keeps your repertoire open to learn other 2nd level spells.