# Are Heightened effects of spells optional?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e

Most Heighten effects are purely beneficial, but some significantly alter the effect of a spell. There is an edge case where you may want to use a high level spell slot but get the effect unaltered. The most obvious instance of this, to me, is [Invisibility](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=164)

> **Duration** 10 minutes
> Cloaked in illusion, the target becomes invisible. This makes it undetected to all creatures, though the creatures can attempt to find the target, making it hidden to them instead. If the target uses a hostile action, the spell ends after that hostile action is completed.
> **Heightened (4th)** The spell lasts 1 minute, but it doesn't end if the target uses a hostile action.

A hypothetical, to illustrate, would be attempting to bypass a Dispel trap or otherwise expecting the Invisibility to be Counteracted while still wanting the 10 minute duration. Could I cast Invisibility using a 4th+ spell slot and still maintain the normal Duration and benefits/limitation of the spell?

Comment: that's an interesting question... it doesn't seem imbalanced to rule that you could cast Invisibility at 4th level without the heightened effects, in the very least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, if you heighten a spell you accept all the changes that come with it.

Heightening spells is described on pg. 299 of the CRB. The extra "heighten" effects are described as something extra when a spell is heightened to the appropriate level. There is no indication that you may choose to accept only some effects of heightening a spell.

Comment: I don't believe there's any harm in actually quoting and interpreting those rules as they can be [here](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=273)